# Create eps files from LaTeX figures

Tags: floats, pdftex, eps

I recently submitted a paper in a journal that was accepted but the editor is requesting all the Figures to be exported in an .eps format. My figures are using different eps files every time but most of my figures have subfigures that have different scales, minipages and so on. For instance Figure 1 has 4 subfigures (each of them is already an eps image) but the editor requires an eps image that has those subfigures placed the way I want them to be placed in the article. I know how to export a LaTeX file as a pdf but I do not know if it is possible to export a LaTeX file as eps file. Also I want to keep the quality of the images intact so I would like to save them with the highest resolution possible. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Ghostscript can do that. Anyway, pdf is a subset of postscript, compressed, so the conversion should be easy.

Comment: Do you want the export to be automated? Or can you do it manually?

Comment: Do you meant "export latex _images_ to pdf" by " export a LaTeX file as a pdf"?

Comment: I would like to be able to directly export a latex file (that calls for eps images) directly to an eps file. Manually is fine too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind doing it manually, you can open the paper PDF using [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) (a vector graphics editor), where you will be prompted to select one of the pages to edit.

From there, you can select the vector objects corresponding to the figure, go to `File > Document Properties > Resize page to content ...`. You should probably delete the other objects, in case the journal eps rendering doesn't respect the new bounding box. Then `File > Save As` and select `EPS` in the file type.

## MWE

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{latex.eps}
      \caption{these fonts won't match}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{latex.eps}
      \caption{but that's the journal's problem}
    \end{subfigure}
  \caption{I'm sorry you have to do this}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image: result]

---

Aside: sounds like this journal needs to update their toolchain. This feels very wrong...

Comment: Thank you this worked well. And I agree, this feels that I have to do the job of the editor :-(.